# How to give line break instring while exporting to pdf in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I am using alivepdf for generating pdf files from my flex project. I am adding a string to my PDF object as follows

```
var str:String = "first line \n second line";
myPDFObject.addText(str,20,20);
```

But the above code does not show new line in the pdf which gets exported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to find a solution. Use addMultiCell instead of addText

Answer (score 0):

Try using the squence: `\r\n`

For example:

```
var str:String = "first line \r\n second line"; 
myPDFObject.addText(str,20,20);
```